# Electron View - Preload - Main communication. How do you call methods of an object?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am writing a new Electron app and to make things a bit more organized I created an object that will encapsulate my display code. My target was to connect the display renderer object with the backend code and keep things really happy.

But, I create the renderer object in the main.js module and I don't know how to get that instance into the preload.js file because all the renderer functions are being called from preload.

What is the right way to tackle this? Global? Is there a way to expose the object instance in main.cs in the preload for each instance I create? (yes, I have multiple renderers created from the same class).

Look at this code which I found on a blog. It's got a similar structure, but I don't see how to access the main.cs renderer object from the preload.

```js
// main.js
    app.whenReady().then(() => {`
        let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({`
            webPreferences: {
                preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
                contextIsolation: true
            },
            width:640,
            height: 480,
            resizable: false
        })
     // ... rest of code
```

```js
//preload.js
    
    const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
    
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
        'electron',
        {
            sendMessage: () => ipcRenderer.send('countdown-start')
        }
    )
```

```js
// renderer.js
    
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', _ => {
        window.electron.sendMessage()
    })
```

Comment: It's not very clear what the structure of the "object that will encapsulate my display code" is, and what your preload script looks like. The code snippets you attached are unrelated to your actual code?

Comment: "_I don't know how to get that instance into the preload.js_" If you did have the renderer object, what would you do with it? "_all the renderer functions are being called from preload_" specifically what functions?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this question is technically incorrect as I have discovered.

The object I create are in the main process, and the renderer process can't access them at all.

What I ended up doing was exposing methods in the main process to work with the object. I called these methods from Preload and things are working fine.

Sorry for a confusing question.